# Change of variable by polar coordinate.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> **Theorem:** Let $U$ and $V$ be open subset of $\Bbb R^d$, and let $T$ be a bijection of $U$ onto $V$ such that $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are both of class $C^{1}$. Then for Borel measurable function $f:V\to \Bbb R$ we have $$ \int_V f~d\lambda = \int_U f(T(x)) \cdot |J_{T}(x)| \cdot \lambda (dx) 
>  \tag {1}$$
> In the sense that if either of integral in (1) exist , then both exist and (1) Holds. where $\lambda$ is usual Lebesgue measure and $ |J_{T}(x)|$ is jacobian .

Now i want to use this theorem combined with Tonelli"s one to evaluate integral $\int_V f~d\lambda$ .

where V={(x,y):$~x^2+y^2<4$ } and $f:V\to \Bbb R$ defined by $(x,y) \mapsto x^2+y^2$.

Now we use above theorem with $V$ is defined as above and $U$={$~$($r$,$\theta$) :$~~$$0<r<2$ and $0<\theta < 2\pi$ } .

and $T:U\to \Bbb R^2$ By $(r,\theta) \mapsto (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. Here $T(U)=V-S$ ,where set $S$ consisting of those points in $V$ which lies on the nonnegative $x$-axis.and here $J_{T}(r,\theta)=r$.

so now
$$
 \int_V f d\lambda = \underbrace{ \int_{V-S} f d\lambda=
\int_{U=(0,2)\times(0,2\pi)} (f\circ T)\cdot r \cdot d\lambda}_\text{Theorem 1}$$

$$\quad \quad ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~= \int_{U=(0,2)\times(0,2\pi)} r^2 \cdot r \cdot d\lambda \tag{2}$$
$$\quad \quad ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~= \int_{(0,2)}\int_{(0,2\pi)} r^2 \cdot r \cdot d\lambda \tag{Tonelli's theorem}$$

Now for above step

(1) Can i use Reimann integral despite of intigrating over **open** interval insted of **closed** one.

(2) If answer of question (1) is yes ,then why it is true ?

(3) If we take $U$={$~$($r$,$\theta$) :$~~$$0<r<2$ and $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$ }. then still we can do same calculation ?

Comment: Answers to 1 and 3 are yes, simply because the difference between the sets is of measure zero. Also, why do you want to use the Riemann integral?

Comment: @peek-a-boo for Riemann integral ,i just want to make sure . and  for question 3 if we take $U$ as in 3 then  i think $T^{-1}$ will not be continuous at for instance $(1.5,0)$ .but i am not able to prove it. and if it is true then Hypothesis of theorem 1 namely ( $T^{-1}$ is $C^1$) will not satisfy.

Comment: Correct, you can’t apply the theorem directly as stated with the modified $U$, **but** the integrals over the open $U$ and the modified $U$ are the same because the difference is measure zero. So, it’s kind of a long-winded answer.

Comment: @peek-a-boo  you said "the difference between the sets is of measure zero." means $\lambda([0,2\pi]-(0,2\pi))=0$  and so we can switch to $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: That’s true if $\lambda$ refers to 1D Lebesgue measure, but aren’t you also asking about the 2D sets? So, letting $U=(0,2)\times (0,2\pi)$ be the open set, we have $\lambda_2(\overline{U}\setminus U)=0$ as well. And $\overline{U}=[0,2]\times [0,2\pi]$ and your modified set is $U’=(0,2)\times [0,2\pi)$ which satisfies $U\subset U’\subset\overline{U}$, and hence $\lambda_2(U’\setminus U)=0$ as well.

Comment: yes i switched set after using Tonelli's theorem.